# My detail page for my app isn't showing in the browser

Tags: python-3.x, django

There is my html template which works perfectly. No template errors.

```
{% extends 'learning_logs/base.html' %}
{% block title %}Topic {% endblock title %}

{% block content %}
 <p>Topic: {{ topic }}</p>
<p>Entries:</p>
 <ul>
 {% for entry in entries %}
<li>
 <p>{{ entry.date_added|date:'M d, Y H:i' }}</p>
 <p>{{ entry.text|linebreaks }}</p>
</li>
 {% empty %}
<li>There are no entries for this topic yet.</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endblock content %}
```

You will find below my view.py. In actual fact the application does not any error.

```
def topic(request, topic_id):
    """Show a single topic and all its entries."""
    topic = Topic.objects.get(id=topic_id)
    entries = topic.entry_set.order_by('date_added')
    context = {'topic': topic, 'entries': entries}
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/topic.html', context)
```

```
    topic = models.ForeignKey('Topic', on_delete = models.CASCADE, max_length = 200)
    text = models.TextField()
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)`
```

Comment: Are you getting a 404 error when you try view the page in your browser?

Comment: Try to `print` **{{ entries.all }}** in your template and see what it shows .

Comment: @Danoram, of course he will not get `404` because he is not using `get_object_or_404` method.